# Excel Matrix: Search Value and provide value next to it

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, phpexcel, excel-2007

I have an Excel table that is a bit messy with different dates below each other.

| User | Date0 | property0 | Date1 | property1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 28/10/21 | 1000 | 27/10/21 | 3000 |
| User2 | 27/10/21 | 2000 | 26/10/21 | 300 |
| User1 | 28/10/21 | 2000 | 25/10/21 | 100 |

I would want to have one separate column for each date as it can be seen below:

| User | Date1 | property1 | Date2 | property2 | Date3 | property3 | Date 4 | property4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| User1 | 28/10/21 | 1000 | 27/10/21 | 3000 | 26/10/21 |  | 25/10/21 |  |
| User2 | 28/10/21 |  | 27/10/21 | 2000 | 26/10/21 | 300 | 25/10/21 |  |
| User1 | 28/10/21 | 2000 | 27/10/21 |  | 26/10/21 |  | 25/10/21 | 100 |

Therefore, I wanted to create a new table with the date values and use an INDEX function that checks the user name and the date to provide the property value. However, I can only search the date in one column in the index function, is there any way to search in the whole matrix and give the value that is next to this date value?

Comment: `User1` with `Property0` returns 2 values in the first table: `1000` and `2000`. Should it return the sum (`3000`) or separate values? Also the first and second table don't show resembling data. Can you update example data to match the actual expected result?

Comment: Does this have to work in 2007? It is relatively easy to do in Power Query, but that did not become available until 2010

Comment: if the input is "User1" & "28/10/21" , there is 2 possible answer. what should the output be?

Answer (score 0):

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NAdH.png)

```
=SUM(IF(($D$4:$F$9=K$3)*($C$4:$C$9=$J4),$E$4:$G$9,""))
```

Notes:

- Falls down for 0 and 'absent' data (both return '0')
- Will work on any version of Excel (the way you enter the formula may differ though, see [here](https://exceljet.net/glossary/array-formula)).  This won't be an issue if no '0's are present;But if 0s aren't an issue then above will do the trick.